# spring eureka - Error resolving template [eureka/status], template might not exist or might not be accessible

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am following this [tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring) to implement a microservice architecture within my project.

First I added the following dependencies to my project:

```
</dependencies>

    ...

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Eureka service registration - CHANGED -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

After that I added a registrationServer class to the project (as described in the tutorial) and set up my config.
The config of my registration server remain very basic:

```
# Ignore JDBC Dependency
# This demo puts 3 applicatons in the same project so they all pick up the
# JDBC Depdendency, but this application doesn't need it.
spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

# Configure this Discovery Server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

server:
  port: 8761  # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

Now as I understood it, at this point I should be able to access http://localhost:8761 and see my setup as tracked by the registration server.
Instead I get a *Whitelabel Error Page* containing the following error message:

```
Error resolving template [eureka/status], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

**Note:** Before adding Eureka, my project consisted of a REST application which I want now to transform into a microservice. The REST service contained a frontend which is organized in the project directories like this:

```
src
 - main
    - resources
       - templates
          - index.html
       - static
          - built
             - bundle.js
```

**Note 2:** Also I tried to disable the thymeleaf template which led to an 404 error when trying to access http://localhost:8761.

```
# Discovery Server Dashboard uses FreeMarker.  Don't want Thymeleaf templates
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    enabled: false     # Disable Thymeleaf 
  datasource:
    type: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [github issue:](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3290#issuecomment-492029213)

*If your project already uses Thymeleaf as its template engine, the Freemarker templates of the Eureka server may not be loaded correctly. In this case it is necessary to configure the template loader manually:*

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  freemarker:
    template-loader-path: classpath:/templates/
    prefer-file-system-access: false
```